# extract aggregated object value from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to store an aggregated objects in `arraylist`

```
public class FlatAddress implements Serializable{
 private String flat_no;
 private String flat_type;
 private String flat_address;
 private int area_code;
 private int state_code;

 private UserPrintApp uPrint;
 //getters and setters..
}
```

In the second step I'm able to store value in `ArrayList` and returning `Collection` to my servlet page

```
Collection<FlatAddress> printAllotLetter = new ArrayList<FlatAddress>();

FlatAddress fa = new FlatAddress();
  UserPrintApp upa = new UserPrintApp();
  upa.setEmp_code(1234);
  upa.setEmp_name("EmpName");
  upa.setEmp_designation("Mgr");
  fa.setuPrint(upa);
  fa.setFlat_no("ad/1");
  fa.setFlat_address("Treemax");
  printAllotLetter.add(fa);
```

while trying extract object from `ArrayList` using `jstl` it says `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException`

```
<c:forEach var="letter" items = "${allotLetterPrint }">
    <c:out value="${letter.emp_code }"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${letter.flat_address }"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

Is it possible to extract aggregated object from collection or I should prepare other collection class to execute what I am trying till now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but in this form:

```
${letter.uPrint.emp_code}
```

instead of

```
${letter.emp_code } <-- letter does not have emp_code property
```

You are looping through the printAllotLetter collection which has variables of type "FlatAddress", which have a uPrint variable of type UserPrintApp which has the emp_code getter.